# Angular 2, @ngrx/store, @ngrx/devtools : bind actions by subscribing to the router?

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx

I'm using on a project using Angular 2 and @ngrx/store. I also use @ngrx/devtools to debug and help me work with this redux implementation.

I would like bind the angular's router with the ngrx's store. So I'll be able to update current route by dispatching an action.

### Context

This is what I've done (it works but this is *not* what I want) :

```
// imports
// ....
// @Component
// ....

@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/home',    name: 'Home',   component: HomeComponent,   useAsDefault: true },
    { path: '/medias',  name: 'Medias', component: MediasComponent }
])
export class MainComponent {
    constructor (private _router:Router, private _store:Store<AppStore>) {
        _router.subscribe(url => _store.dispatch(changeUrl(url)));
    }
}
```

**changeUrl** is an action creator.

So when Angular detects a route update an action is dispatched and my state is updating.

And it works well ! Using @ngrx/devtools, I can see the actions correctly dispatched, the store is updated but.. This is the opposite of what I want because **angular** do the job and update **redux**. So if I rollback an action, my view is **not** updated.

### It's simple !

*"All what I have to do is to dispatch an action when click on a nav link inside the action creator, redirect using Angular's methods."*

Yep. But no, I think it's not a good way to go because of :

- `<a [routerLink]="routeName">Link</a>` provided by Angular becomes useless.
- It seems difficult to use Angular's DI to inject the `Router` inside my actions creator because actions creators are basically functions. Not angular's components.

### What to do ?

This is the question. I don't really know how to bind Angular's router & @ngrx/store correctly.

Comment: I haven't used it yet, but this looks promising: https://github.com/CodeSequence/ngrx-store-router

Comment: Intersting, I'll check this. Thanks :)